# get Hard Link Count in Java

Tags: java, linux, posix, solaris-10

I need something to get the hard link count from a file in a solaris10 os in java.

parsing ls -l is not an option.

I tried using posix for java http://bmsi.com/java/posix/index.html but couldn't manage to get it working.

Is there any other lightweight API or code to get this info?

Comment: "ls -l | wc -l" doesn't work ?

Comment: @alfasin: Short of _parsing `ls` is not an option_?

Comment: @K-ballo sorry - I didn't understand your Q.

Comment: @alfasin: The question states that parsing `ls` is not an option.

Comment: @K-ballo right! and I asked if the reason is that it doesn't work or is there another reason, cause if there's another reason - maybe it's something we should consider when we try to answer.

Comment: i can parse ls -l and it will work but its not the preferred solution.

Comment: This question and answers are rather old. What is the state in 2021 with Java 11+?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java 7 you can use the new [file attributes API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) to get it with
`java.nio.file.Files.getAttribute(path, "unix:nlink")`.

The "unix" attribute view is not actually defined as part of the standard API (and the "posix" view does not give you nlink), but is available in the standard Oracle/OpenJDK implementation.
On the other hand *creating* a link is now available with the standard `createLink` method on `Files`. Go figure.

Comment: Awesome... too bad we have se 6 as our standard right now. :(

Comment: So you better plan for upgrade, as [Java 6 will be out of life in 5 months (November 2012)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html).

Answer (score 2):

Short of [using JNI](http://www.nag.co.uk/IndustryArticles/CallingCLibraryRoutinesfromJava.pdf) and `stat`/`lstat` in C the only thing better than parsing ls would be to run:

```
stat --format=%h filename
```

which just outputs a number and is easy to parse.

But it all gets complicated when there can be non-ascii characters in filenames. You'd need to convert filename to native encoding, and sometimes not all characters allowed in filename can be converted (if native encoding isn't some kind of unicode).

Comment: Cool it works. Thanks! but one of the servers I've tested it on doesn't have stat... Are there any other solutions which doesn't require installation or something... thanks in advance. :)

Comment: is stat a linux only application?

Answer (score 0):

Also consider trying the [jnr-posix](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix) implementation of **stat(2)** for this.