# Is there an easy way to determine if a file is a hard link using Java in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, java-7, hardlink

I noticed that Java 7 has added a lot of new useful file operations with the new Paths and Files etc. classes in NIO.  However, it seems that Java 7 has only added file operations to handle soft links or created hard links.

Is there a way to identify (not just create) hard links using standard Java without bringing in any third party libraries?

I've seen the "unix:nlink" question and have updated to be more specific. This view does not work in a Windows environment.

I suppose the heart of the issue lies in whether or not Java can get inode information from the OS and even with the new libraries I believe the answer to be No, unless someone knows otherwise.

Comment: symlink != hardlink; try to avoid inaccurate tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045321/get-hard-link-count-in-java

Comment: Why was this question closed? The "possible duplicate", which asks for Unix, does not answer the question for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 there is a simple solution:

```
java.nio.file.Files.getAttribute( Paths.get( "/", "path" ), "unix:nlink" );
```

Comment: How about for a windows platform?  And perhaps you have a link to the different attribute String arguments?

Comment: Thank's for reminding me of the right arguments. I'm not sure if there's any windows corresponding attribute, but I can't realize your problem. The folowing code works in that way as it should - throwing exceptions and start again: while ( true ) { 
   try {
    System.out.println(java.nio.file.Files.getAttribute( Paths.get( "ABC", "xzf" ), "isDirectory" ).toString());
   } catch ( IOException except ) {
    System.out.println(except.getStackTrace()[0]);
   }
  }

Comment: I'm wishing Java could do something it can't apparently.