# Detect if 2 paths are hard-linked together

Tags: java, nio

If I have 2 `Path`s for files, both share the same `FileStore`, how can I verify with Java 17 whether they are pointing to the same file on disk (are hard-linked)? For Unix-like systems there seems at least to be a way to verify whether a file has other hardlinks ([get Hard Link Count in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045321/get-hard-link-count-in-java)), but on Windows/NTFS I haven't yet found a way to get either information, except of invoking `fsutil hardlink list <file-path>` and parsing the output. If necessary, a workaround using JNA would also fine for me.

PS: I have already searched Stackoverflow, but only found similar questions for Python or C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Files.isSameFile(path1, path2)` checks whether they are hard-linked.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it can be done within Java alone.

Try to use [getCanonicalPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) to at least get around relative and absolute path names. But this hardly gets you around symlinks, or symlinks in parent folders.

For such things in Linux systems there is the [readlink](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html) command. There is lots to be found here on StackOverflow about it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=readlink

For Windows you already mentioned fsutil.